# an exception of type 'system.nullreferenceexception' occurred in controlador.dll (en TempData)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

A que se debe mi error? El error surge en el método de acción About, justo en la linea  ViewBag.Mensaje =TempData["datos"].ToString();

[image: El error surge en el método de acción About, justo en el TempData["datos"].ToString();]

[image: En el action index creo el TempData que compartira informacion a mi otro metodo de accion About, me botaba error pero lo converti a cadena, aun asi sale ese error.]

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Mensaje = "Bienvenidos al Curso de ASP.NET MVC";
        ViewBag.Profesor = "Carlos Garcia";
        ViewBag.Alumno = "Juan Perez";
    //TempData["nombre"]=valor =>permite compartir entre metodos de accion
     TempData["datos"] = "Profesor:" + ViewBag.Profesor + " y Alumno:" + ViewBag.Alumno;

        return View();
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------


    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Mensaje = TempData["datos"].ToString();
        //ViewBag => Variable Global que permite almacenar valores
        //para ser usados en las vistas ,es un objeto especial que nos permite enviar informacion desde el action hasta la vista
        //ViewBag.NombredeVariable = valor
        ViewBag.Message = "Descripcion de la Pagina Web MVC.";

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Hola Christian. Deberías editar la pregunta para añadir el código y el mensaje de error como texto. Las imágenes no se indexan y no todos los usuarios pueden ver su contenido. Lee [ask] para más información y consejos y completa el [tour] para ver cómo funciona el sitio en general (y ganar tu primera medalla).

Comment: El error te da porque `TemData["datos"]` es nulo. Al intentar ejecutar el método `ToString` de un valor nulo se produce el error. De todas formas ¿Por qué conviertes a `string` un valor que sólo puede ser `string`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que el ViewBag es válido para el request actual, es decir, cuando lo estás llenando en la vista Index y navegas a otra vista, el ViewBag estará vacío otra vez.
Si quieres una variable que sea válida durante la sesión, usa [Session](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/6ad7zeeb(v=vs.100).aspx).
En tu médotod Index podrías hacer algo como:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["datos"] = "Profesor:" + ViewBag.Profesor + " y Alumno:" + ViewBag.Alumno;
```

Y en el método About:

```
ViewBag.Mensaje = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["datos"].ToString();
```

Lo que esté guardado en Session será válido durante la sesión del usuario. Para otro usuario, el objeto estará vacío.